# Automatic Download from webpage python

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to download the data from this page https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/Market-data1/Power-system-data/Production1/Wind-Power-Prognosis/DK/Hourly/?view=table

As you can see there is a button that can automatically export the data to Excel on the right. I want to create something that is able to automatically export the data present on this to Excel everyday - kind of like a scraper, but I am not able to figure it out.

So far this is my code

```
import urllib2  
nord='https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/Market-data1/Power-system- 
data/Production1/Wind-Power-Prognosis/DK/Hourly/?view=table'  
page=urllib2.urlopen(nord)  
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
soup=bs(page)
pretty=soup.prettify()
all_links=soup.find_all("a")
for link in all_links:
    print link.get("href")
all_tables=soup.find_all('tables')
right_table=soup.find('table', class_='ng-scope')
```

And this is where I am stuck, because it seems that the table class is not defined.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Usual tools for this are Beuatiful Soup or Selenium depending on exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @philipI have added what I tried to do in the description now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html)** module for this.

**Ex:**

```
import requests
url = "https://www.nordpoolgroup.com/api/marketdata/exportxls"

r = requests.post(url)   #POST Request
with open('data_123.xls', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

Comment: It didnt quite work, the downloaed excel file does not seem to have any data on it